# LaTeX Biblatex Build for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, latex

I'm new to using Linux (Ubuntu 16.04), but I'm committed to full immersion. A catch to this is that I am writing a masters thesis in LaTeX and I ran into bibliography issues. Apparently this is a common [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/biber/+bug/1565842) with Ubuntu 16.04. I think maybe this is related. Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-history}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
```

The error it throws is "! LaTeX Error: File `biblatex-history.sty' not found."

This issue seems to be discussed in a lot of special cases or in bits and pieces, but I can't seem to find a complete answer of how to fix this, or how to be sure if this is the bug that was found when Ubuntu updated. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: This might be better asked over on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The bug report you linked to says a fix has been released. Are you sure your problem is related to it?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug as you have linked however there is a workaround that is reported to work. Try [this.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/biber/+bug/1565842/comments/24)

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/biber/+bug/1565842

Edit: It appears there is a newer source package here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/biber

As far as the specific error introduced by your preamble you might examine    `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-history}` and determine if you indeed have the package named or if there is a typo involved.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/how-can-i-insert-by-bib-file-into-my-tex-file

and

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20317/internal-bibliography-with-biblatex

Comment: It should be fixed. Just check you have installed and up-to-date *both* `biber` and `texlive-bibtex-extra`.

Comment: @Rmano Can you clarify? fixed in what version? And can you verify that the fix has been published in the repositories? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry --- the incompatibility of biber and biblatex has been fixed, in 16.04, with biber 2.4-1ubuntu1.16.04.1. Nevertheless, I can't find `biblatex-history.sty` anywhere, so that problem is still there.

Comment: @Rmano I can't find any mention of that particular file anywhere either.. I suppose it could be a typo or a missing custom user created file. as mentioned here: http://learn.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_styles#Biblatex_styles